# Division by zero using shell

Tags: shell, division

I'm writing a shell program using while commands to prevent division by zero and to exit the program when the user types 99. Everytime i run it i get an error for the input of the second number which in turn does not give me the answer. Below is my attempt at this problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
firstNum=0
secondNum=0
answer=0
while true firstNum != 99, secondNum != 99 do
read -p "Enter first number" firstNum
read -p "Enter second number" secondNum
echo "first num $firstNum"
echo "second Num $secondNum"
if ["$secondNum" = "0"]
then
    exit 1
else
    echo "first number / second Number = $((firstNum/secondNum))"
    echo "Answer = $answer"
fi
do 
exit
done
```

And the following is the error message that i get

```
./example.sh: 10: ./example.sh: [2: not found
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a few typos.

Replace this:

```
if ["$secondNum" = "0"] then
    exit 1
then
    echo "1st number / 2nd number = $((firstNum/secondNum))"
    echo "Answer = $answer"
fi
```

with this:

```
if [ "$secondNum" = "0" ]
then
    exit 1
else
    echo "1st number / 2nd number = $((firstNum/secondNum))"
    echo "Answer = $answer"
fi
```

Bash is finicky.  Ensure `then` is on the next line and not same line as the `if`, you also had `then` instead of `else` on your 3rd line.

Comment: The answer now displays however, I still get the original error message about the second number. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: I don't see any error on my end, so maybe update your code snippet above, so we can test it.

Comment: Also, your `while` statement doesn't look familiar to me, i'd do a search for `bash while` on the internet for examples to ensure your format is correct.

Comment: After looking at your code more closely, your `while` loop doesn't make any sense, you're checking the condition before the value is even set.  Best to remove the `while` loop altogether, and add an additional `if` condition to check for 99.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be simplified

```
while true; do
    read -p "Enter first number: " firstNum
    [[ "$firstNum" -eq 99 ]] && break

    read -p "Enter second number: " secondNum
    case "$secondNum" in
        99) break ;;
        0) echo "div by zero, try again"; continue ;;
    esac

    echo "first number / second Number = $(bc -l <<< "$firstNum/$secondNum")"
done
```

I'm calling out to `bc` to get floating point arithmetic. With the shell you're limited to integers only.

`<<<` is a "here-string", a string to pass to bc's stdin

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty good to me, but I changed the POSIX shell test around a bit to test for values less than 99 instead of 99 itself. And there was a stray `do` near the bottom of the script which I removed. Bash has `[[]]` style test syntax too which you may want to switch to at some point.

```
#!/bin/bash

firstNum=0
secondNum=0
answer=0

while [ "$firstNum" -lt 99 -a "$secondNum" -lt 99 ]
do
    read -p "Enter first number " firstNum
    read -p "Enter second number " secondNum
    printf "first num $firstNum\n"
    printf "second Num $secondNum\n"
    if [ "$secondNum" = 0 ]
    then
        printf "$secondNum was a zero, exiting!\n"
        exit 1
    else
        printf "first num / second Num = \$(($firstNum / $secondNum))\n"
        answer=$(( firstNum / secondNum))
        printf "Answer = $answer\n"
    fi
done
```

If you are interested in learning the Bash test syntax `[[]]` (it's a bit more powerful than POSIX shell's test(1) `[]`) here is an example which uses it:

```
#!/bin/bash

firstNum=0
secondNum=0
answer=0

while [[ "$firstNum" < 99 && "$secondNum" < 99 ]]
do
    read -p "Enter first number " firstNum
    read -p "Enter second number " secondNum
    printf "first num $firstNum\n"
    printf "second Num $secondNum\n"
    if [[ "$secondNum" == 0 ]]
    then
        printf "$secondNum was a zero, exiting!\n"
        exit 1
    else
        printf "first num / second Num = \$(($firstNum / $secondNum))\n"
        answer=$(( firstNum / secondNum))
        printf "Answer = $answer\n"
    fi
done
```

It may also be advisable to move the tests into the body of the `while` loop and instead use the convention 'while [[ 1 ]]' to create a continuous loop. Here is an example doing that (using bash test syntax `[[]]`) and using `bc` so the script supports floating point arithmetic:

```
#!/bin/bash

firstNum=0
secondNum=0
answer=0

while [[ 1 ]]
do
    read -p "Enter first number " firstNum
    read -p "Enter second number " secondNum
    printf "first num $firstNum\n"
    printf "second Num $secondNum\n"
    case "$firstNum" in
        99) printf "Invalid values\n"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac

    case "$secondNum" in
        99) printf "Invalid values\n"
            exit 1
            ;;
         0) printf "Invalid values\n"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac

    answer=$(printf "$firstNum / $secondNum\n" | bc -l)
    printf "Floating point supported answer using bc: = $answer \n"
done
```